# Pass data in vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am trying to get the data "voltage" from the current component into the "home-component".

The "home-component" is used like this in the current component:

```
    <v-list-tile to="/">
      <v-list-tile-action>
        <v-icon>home</v-icon>
      </v-list-tile-action>
      <v-list-tile-content>
        <v-list-tile-title>Home</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile-content>
    </v-list-tile>
```

How do I pass data to the home component.

The route looks like this:

```
  path: '/',
  name: 'home',
  component: Home
```

And that's the data section containing "voltage":

```
data() {
    return {
      drawer: null,
      turnedOn: false,
      buttonText: 'Turn Off',
      connection: null,
      voltage: '0',
    }
  }
```

The most common approach to pass data from a parent to a child is using "props:". But I don't know how to use this, while using the route of the child.

Comment: Can you make it more clear about the current component and home component?

Answer (score 0):

Passing props to a route component [is possible](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html), but I believe using a store is a simpler and more straight-forward solution.

---

It doesn't have to be [`pinia`](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) (although it's the recommended solution, for a myriad of reasons).

By definition, a store is any reactive state exported for the purpose of being imported into separate components so they would all receive any modifications to that state in real time.

The simplest forms of stores are [reactive()](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state) and [ref()](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#reactive-variables-with-ref).

Generic example:

***store.js*** (or `.ts`)

```js
import { reactive } from 'vue'
export const state = reactive({
  foo: 'bar'
})
```

**Usage:**

```js
import { state } from './path/to/store'

// setting:
state.foo = 'baz'

// any other component importing and using `state.foo` in its `<script>`
// or `<template>` will receive the update in real time
// It can even be used with `v-model`!
```